# Regular expression to extract different parts of URL and path

Tags: regex

Consider URLs like

```
https://stackoverflow.com/v1/summary/1243PQ/details/P1/9981
http://stackoverflow.com/v2/summary/saas?test=123
```

I need a regular expression to match these URLs and convert them into

```
stackoverflow.com:v1:summary:1243PQ:details:P1:9981
stackoverflow.com:v2:summary:saas
```

I need to build a single rule using regex where I can extract paths using `$1`, `$2`, etc. without using any javascript logic as I need to use it in a classification rule builder tool.
I tried this URL contains `^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?` and extracted `$4:$5` which returns `stackoverflow.com:v1/summary/1243PQ/details/P1/9981`

But, this is incorrect. Can anyone help me with the correct regex for this?

Comment: Can you tell us the regex flavor (or the programming language you are using)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

#### Regex

```
/(?:https?:\/\/([^\/?\s#]+))?\/([^\/?\s#]*)(?:[\?#].*)?/g
```

#### Substitution

```
$1:$2
```

---

```
(?:                     non-capturing group
    https?:\/\/         "http://" or "https://"
    ([^\/?\s#]+)        capture the domain and put it in group 1
)?                      make this capture optional
\/                      "/"
([^\/?\s#]*)            one segment of the url path, capture it in group 2
(?:[\?#].*)?            an optional non-capturing group for consuming query string or # anchor at the end
```

Check the [test cases](https://regex101.com/r/If8WDw/1/)

---

### Update

If you can't use `g` flag for substitution, there's no better way but bruteforce all the combinations:

You need to add a `\/([^\/?#\s]+)` and `:$2` etc for each segment of the url path:

---

- `https://stackoverflow.com`

```
^https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?([^\/?#\s]+)\/?(?:[#?].*)?$
```

```
$1
```

---

- `https://stackoverflow.com/path1`

```
^https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?([^\/?#\s]+)\/([^\/?#\s]+)\/?(?:[#?].*)?$
```

```
$1:$2
```

---

- `https://stackoverflow.com/path1/path2`

```
^https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?([^\/?#\s]+)\/([^\/?#\s]+)\/([^\/?#\s]+)\/?(?:[#?].*)?$
```

```
$1:$2:$3
```

---

- `https://stackoverflow.com/path1/path2/path3`

```
^https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?([^\/?#\s]+)\/([^\/?#\s]+)\/([^\/?#\s]+)\/([^\/?#\s]+)\/?(?:[#?].*)?$
```

```
$1:$2:$3:$4
```

---

- `https://stackoverflow.com/path1/path2/path3/path4`

```
^https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?([^\/?#\s]+)\/([^\/?#\s]+)\/([^\/?#\s]+)\/([^\/?#\s]+)\/([^\/?#\s]+)\/?(?:[#?].*)?$
```

```
$1:$2:$3:$4:$5
```

---

- `https://stackoverflow.com/path1/path2/path3/path4/path5`

```
^https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?([^\/?#\s]+)\/([^\/?#\s]+)\/([^\/?#\s]+)\/([^\/?#\s]+)\/([^\/?#\s]+)\/([^\/?#\s]+)\/?(?:[#?].*)?$
```

```
$1:$2:$3:$4:$5:$6
```

Comment: This gives only the first section of the path and the rest are lost. It changes https://stackoverflow.com/v1/summary/1243PQ/details/P1/9981 to "stackoverflow.com:v1". But I want to extaract all parts of the path "stackoverflow.com:v1:summary:1243PQ:details:P1:9981" The number of parameters in path are variable

Comment: @user16045165 Don't forget the `g` flag for multiple matches

Comment: This works in regex  tester but not inside classification builder. On adding g flag it gives error saying regex invalid and if I don't add then it gives "stackoverflow.com:v1". I think I will need to add different regexs for different no. of paths in URL. I think the maximum paths in URL will be 6 depending on the site structure. Can you help me with 6 different regex for converting urls like
1.https://www.stackoverflow.com to 'stackoverflow.com'
2.https://www.stackoverflow.com/test to  'stackoverflow.com:test'
3. https://www.stackoverflow.com/test/abc to  'stackoverflow.com:test:abc' ,etc.

Comment: @user16045165 I've updated a workaround according to your description. See if it helps

Comment: Thank you so much for this. There are just 2 issues with this. For eg: If I take this '^https?:\/\/([^\/?#\s]+)\/([^\/?#\s]+).*$', it also matches the higher levels 'https://stackoverflow.com/path1/path2' 
I tried changing it to ''^https?:\/\/([^\/?#\s]+)\/([^\/?#\s]+)$' but then it doesn't considers URLs with query string like 'https://stackoverflow.com/path1?test=abc'. 
Also if there is www. in url I want to remove it if possible so 'www.test.com/path?test=abc' should be 'test.com:path' and it should not match 'www.test.com/path1/path2'

Comment: @user16045165 How about now?